# Angular 2 FormBuilder disable fields on checkbox select

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I have build angular cli project and have a form with checkbox. Some of the fields must disable on checkbox select.

Form is as follows:

[image]

need to disable/enable password, new password and re type password fields on checkbox select event.

Html

```
<form [formGroup]="userProfileForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(userProfileForm.value)">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> {{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.USER_NAME' | translate }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="userProfileForm.controls['userName']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>{{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.DISPLAY_NAME' | translate }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="userProfileForm.controls['displayName']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>{{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.EMAIL' | translate }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="userProfileForm.controls['email']">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" value="isResetPassword" name="isResetPassword" [formControl]="userProfileForm.controls['isResetPassword']">  
                 {{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.RESET_PASSWORD' | translate }}
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>{{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.PASSWORD' | translate }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" [formControl]="userProfileForm.controls['password']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>{{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.NEW_PASSWORD' | translate }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" [formControl]="userProfileForm.controls['newPassword']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>{{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.RE_TYPE_PASSWORD' | translate }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" [formControl]="userProfileForm.controls['reTypePassword']">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

ts code

```
this.isResetPassword = true;
this.userProfileForm = formBuilder.group({
    'userName': [null, [Validators.required]],
    'displayName': [null],
    'email': [null, [Validators.required]],
    'isResetPassword': this.isResetPassword,
    'password': [{
        value: null,
        disabled: this.isResetPassword
    }],
    'newPassword': [{
        value: null,
        disabled: this.isResetPassword
    }],
    'reTypePassword': [{
        value: null,
        disabled: this.isResetPassword
    }]
})
```

Form has built inside the constructor.
How can I disable/enable the above fields on check box select.

Comment: As per above answers use formControlName. On click event on checkbox call one eventhandler in which toggle value of isResetPassword and then add below statement.
`userProfileForm.updateValueAndValidity();`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

At first, I believe that you want to *enable* fields if and only if `isResetPassword` *checkbox* is selected, right? If so, here we go:

1 - The construction of the form should be like this:

```
this.userProfileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  // ...
  password: [{
    value: null,
    disabled: !this.isResetPassword
  }],
  newPassword: [{
    value: null,
    disabled: !this.isResetPassword
  }],
  reTypePassword: [{
    value: null,
    disabled: !this.isResetPassword
  }]
});
```

Note that here I'm disabling inputs only when `this.isResetPassword` is false.

2 - To detect changes on your `<input type="checkbox">`, you can use either `(change)` in **template**:

```
<label>
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    [formControl]="userProfileForm.controls['isResetPassword']" 
    (change)="handleChange($event)">
  {{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.RESET_PASSWORD' | translate }}
</label>
```

... or even, in **component**, using `valueChanges`:

```
this.userProfileForm.get('isResetPassword').valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.handleChange(value));
```

And, of course, here's the `function` to manipulate the state of fields.

```
handleChange(value: boolean): void {
  const passwordCtrl = this.userProfileForm.get('password');
  const newPasswordCtrl = this.userProfileForm.get('newPassword');
  const reTypePasswordCtrl = this.userProfileForm.get('reTypePassword');

  if (value) {
    passwordCtrl.enable();
    newPasswordCtrl.enable();
    reTypePasswordCtrl.enable();
  } else {
    passwordCtrl.disable();
    newPasswordCtrl.disable();
    reTypePasswordCtrl.disable();
  }
}
```

---

Some tips:

1 - Although it's only a matter of preference, it's worth to mention that you don't need to use `[formControl]` like this:

```
[formControl]="userProfileForm.controls['isResetPassword']"
```

Instead, you can simply use `formControlName`:

```
formControlName="isResetPassword"
```

Note that you can do the same for all your *controls*.

2 - You don't need to pass the *form value* in `(ngSubmit)` since you've already the reference of `userProfileForm` in `form`.

Instead of:

```
(ngSubmit)="submitForm(userProfileForm.value)"

submitForm(value: any) { console.log(value); }
```

This:

```
(ngSubmit)="submitForm()"

submitForm() { console.log(this.userProfileForm.value); }
```

3 - If you want to see the `value` of disabled inputs, instead of `.value`, you should use `.getRawValue()`, like this:

```
this.userProfileForm.getRawValue();
```

---

[DEMO (using `(change)`)](http://plnkr.co/edit/bJL0CM3pPuuKl9dxY3rn?p=preview)

[DEMO (using `valueChanges`)](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rptr3H1D4FoBKu8XHR2p?p=info)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way would be to create a form group just for the passwords:

```
this.userProfileForm = formBuilder.group({
  'userName': [null, [Validators.required]],
  'displayName': [null],
  'email': [null, [Validators.required]],
  password: formBuilder.group({
    'isResetPassword': this.isResetPassword,
    'password': [null],
    'newPassword': [null],
    'reTypePassword': [null]
  })
})
```

Then on your template change the passwords col to this:

```
<div class="col" formGroupName="password>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isResetPassword">  
      {{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.RESET_PASSWORD' | translate }}
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label>{{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.PASSWORD' | translate }}</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" formControlName="password" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label>{{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.NEW_PASSWORD' | translate }}</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" formControlName="newPassword">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label>{{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.RE_TYPE_PASSWORD' | translate }}</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" formControlName="reTypePassword">
  </div>
</div>
```

on your component:

```
//when value changes, to disable all the fields just do this
this.userProfileForm.controls.password.disable();
// to enable them back
this.userProfileForm.controls.password.enable();
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the methods on this post works but you need to do it with a `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.disable) {
       this.userProfileForm.controls.password.disable();
    }
    else {
        this.userProfileForm.controls.password.enable();
    }
});
```

Looks like an Angular bug, issues [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19251) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22556)

Answer (score 0):

You also can reference to your form setting in the control you want disable
e.g.

```
[disabled]="!formName.value.fieldName"
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `[formControl]` for your controls in the template, use `formControlName`.

Your form will look like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="userProfileForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(userProfileForm.value)">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> {{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.USER_NAME' | translate }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="userName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>{{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.DISPLAY_NAME' | translate }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="displayName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>{{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.EMAIL' | translate }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" value="isResetPassword" name="isResetPassword" formControlName="isResetPassword">  
                 {{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.RESET_PASSWORD' | translate }}
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>{{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.PASSWORD' | translate }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" formControlName="password" [attr.disabled]="userProfileForm.value.isResetPassword?'':null">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>{{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.NEW_PASSWORD' | translate }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" formControlName="newPassword" [attr.disabled]="userProfileForm.value.isResetPassword?'':null">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>{{ 'USER_PROFILE_MODEL.RE_TYPE_PASSWORD' | translate }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" formControlName="reTypePassword" [attr.disabled]="userProfileForm.value.isResetPassword?'':null">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

And you have to define your form like this:

```
this.userProfileForm = formBuilder.group({
    'userName': [null, [Validators.required]],
    'displayName': [null],
    'email': [null, [Validators.required]],
    'isResetPassword': [false],
    'password': [null],
    'newPassword': [null],
    'reTypePassword': [null]
})
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to write a callBack on click of checkbox like `(click)="checkBoxClicked()"` and in component define callback function as follows

```
checkBoxClicked() {
 if(!this.userProfileForm.controls.isResetPassword.value) {
   this.userProfileForm.controls.password.disable();
   this.userProfileForm.controls.newPassword.disable();
   this.userProfileForm.controls.reTypePassword.disable();
 }else {
   this.userProfileForm.controls.password.enable();
   this.userProfileForm.controls.newPassword.enable();
   this.userProfileForm.controls.reTypePassword.enable();
 }
}
```