# Check box selection to enable /disable textboxes using angular reactive forms

Tags: angular

Onload itself textboxes are disabled mode, if we select checkbox, textboxes should be enabled and uncheck  textboxes should be disabled mode and no error borders. I tried below code, validations are working fine but unable to disable/enable checkboxes, please help me the issue..

```
<input type="checkbox" #chkEnable ngModel />
<label>CheckBox Select to Enable/Disable</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" [disabled]="!chkEnable.checked" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': ( f.firstName.touched)  && f.firstName.errors }" />
    <div *ngIf="((f.firstName.touched) && f.firstName.errors)" class="invalid-input"></div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-to-enable-disable?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot disable reactive form field from HTML. If you wan to disable reactive from you can use disable() method from reactive form.

After these changes you can disable field.

1. remove [disabled] property from input.
2. add (change) event to checkbox

`<input  type="checkbox" #chkEnable ngModel (change)="disableField(chkEnable.checked)" />`

3. in .ts file create method to disable input

   `disableField(checked) { Object.keys(this.f).forEach(key => { if (!checked) { this.f[key].disable(); } else { this.f[key].enable(); } }); }`

using this method you can disable all fields in from.

Also if you want to make fields disable on load you can change your form by below code

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstName: [{ value: "", disabled: true }, Validators.required],
  lastName: [{ value: "", disabled: true }, Validators.required]
});
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-to-enable-disable-8sqipf?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969382/angular-2-formbuilder-disable-fields-on-checkbox-select

In this link you can find other ways to disable input fields

Comment: Hi @Kinjal, Could you please suggest me the below question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67549092/how-to-update-the-params-for-every-pagination-button-clicks?noredirect=1#comment119430695_67549092

Answer (score 0):

we create the change event for checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="isChecked($event)">
   
isChecked(event){
    let isChecked=event.target.value; 
    if (isChecked) {                         
          this.registerForm.get("firstName").disable();
          this.registerForm.get("lastName").disable();
    } 
    else {
          this.registerForm.get("firstName").enable();
          this.registerForm.get("lastName").enable();
    }
}
```

I attached the link also https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-to-enable-disable-2bqfkf?file=app/app.component.ts